# Why can it be that it does not stop taking builds in Docker?

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I share a dockerfile and when building, it takes 80gb build directly as in the picture below and does not stop and creates a mysql file directly, one 80gb, mysql is not used in the project.  I wonder why it could be?

[image]

I do not encounter anything while building in other projects, only in this project.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How can I minimally exemplify something I do not understand? If I could exemplify, I would try to look for the source of the problem.